# Monitor/Manage Remote Site

Tags: remote-access

I'm not sure if this is the right community for this question, but if not please let me know and I'll move the question.

We have some AIS equipment and converters at a remote tower site.  The site has an ADSL line to it which is used to send data from the receivers to a website.  I am looking for a way to be able to login remotely to the site and manage the equipment without having to travel to the tower itself (40 min flight and 30 min drive).  I am thinking about putting a small fanless computer out there which would allow for DDNS and remote login and from it I could connect to the other equipment.  Has anyone had any experience with this type of remote monitoring and what did you use?

Answer (score 0):

I work for a company that manages and monitors remote equipment, often installed alongside highway corridors. These installations tend to be isolated, and often may have a wireless (cellular network) or satellite internet connection. Depending on location, they may experience a wide range of temperatures, humidity, and other harsh conditions.

Most installations such as these use an industrial computer, system on a chip (SoC), or a custom hardware solution that allows for the environmental conditions. The remote locations I typically work with have enclosures for computer and network equipment. Depending on your budget and the conditions at the remote location, you may want to install something like a [BeagleBone Black*](http://beagleboard.org/BLACK) or a full-blown industrial computer (i.e. [Nexcom](http://www.nexcom.com/), [Portwell](http://www.portwell.com/products/products.php), etc.)

**The operating temperature for the Beaglebone Black is difficult to find, but I've found [posts](http://osdir.com/ml/beagleboard/2013-09/msg01406.html) where people have tested it to 70°C with success. For the low price, if you're familiar with Linux, it may be a good place to start.*

Comment: Luckily for me, the computer would be installed at a large tower installation that handles a wide array of communications equipment so everything is housed in an air-conditioned building.  So I don't need to worry about weather, dust, temperature and therefore don't need an industrial PC.  What OS do you use on the BeagleBone and can it do basic DDNS and startup a web-browser (the equipment I'm talking to uses a web page for configuration and monitoring)?

Comment: I personally haven't used a BBB for remote installations, but I have seen others using them with Debian or Ubuntu Linux. I'm not sure if they support DDNS but they do have standard DHCP capability, and include a web browser. I want to say it's Firefox but I'm not sure.